# Things that were miracles for us - or "to us"?

Tags: prepositions

Let's take two sentences:

> Things that were miracles **for us** yesterday seem to be common today.

and

> Things that were miracles **to us** yesterday seem to be common today.

Are they equal in meaning? Or does the first imply "miracles prepared for us" and the second, "things that we contemplated as miracles (regardless of the possible recipient or user of these things)"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Things that were miracles to us yesterday seem to be common today.

would be my preferred form.
As you say, "things that we contemplated as miracles (regardless of the possible recipient or user of these things)" would appear to be the intent.
Things that we regarded as miracles;
[even if you  *Yoda-ise* it, it still works. "things we perceived as miraculous, they appeared to be." ]

> Things that were miracles for us yesterday seem to be common today.

I'm not sure it's *wrong* [grammarians please correct me if so] but there's the *very* slight hint of "the *manna* that inexplicably appears on our front lawn each morning has lost its ability to generate any sense of awe, even though it may still, technically, be a miracle."

*Edit:* I think the second one does just give a hint that the miracle was done for our specific benefit; the first to the benefit of 'humankind in general'

'manna on front lawn' & 'smartphone technology' can be one & the same thing, I guess. It's not like I really know how either of them actually works.

[Clarke's 3rd Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clarke's_three_laws) - "Any sufficiently advanced technology is indistinguishable from magic."

Comment: I'm not sure I like my own 2nd explanation… might need to rethink.

Comment: I rethunk, I think;)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, no, depends.

Roughly speaking, they are equivalent: the first *could* but does not *necessarily* imply that you were the subject of the miracle.

They are equivalent when talking about miracles where "we" [you and the person you are addressing] are not the subject.

They are not equivalent if you use the former to refer to miracles of which "we" are the subject, as the latter wouldn't fit this usage.

That said, I doubt anyone would use **miracles for us** to refer to miracles of which we are the subject. Particularly in your example sentences.

Answer (score 1):

This comes from my own volition!

Basically the question is *something **for** you* and *something **to** you*. My two cents are...if something is *for* you, you are aware of it and are directly involved. Whereas if something is *to* you, it's affecting you. You might be aware of it but may not be involved in that.

Let's take *importance* for better understanding...

In most of the cases, when *someone* tells you (indirect involvement of yours), we often observe *to*.

> Besides taking care of the things that are important ***to*** you, you need to give due priority to your partner as well.

But when I speak, it links me directly and I am *aware* of the importance.

> Find me a job. It is important **for** me.

Now the sentences in concern...

> Things that were miracles ***for/to*** us yesterday seem to be common today.

As I just tried to make my point clear, I incline toward *to* because of our *indirect* involvement.

*(I just don't know how did I answer this!)*